# How to hasMany without foreign key in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables, say:

```
TAB1
----
id
tab1_md5


TAB2
----
id
tab2_md5
```

I would like to create a hasMany relation without foreignKey to be able to use cakephp recursive stuff but don't know how to create the relationship.
I've tried with:

```
var $hasMany = array(
'Tab2' => array(
'className' => 'Tab2',
'foreignKey' => false))
```

but i don't know what i should specify in condition

EDIT: the relation is tab1.tab1_md5=tab2.tab2_md5

Comment: What is the condition for the relationship, how are the two tables related‽

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by being "able to use cakephp recursive stuff"?

Comment: I believe he means the recursive variable in the controller to be able to pull the related models when he searches for model data

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do a hasMany relationship without using a foreign key. CakePHP, at that point, has no idea how these tables should be related. Without knowing the relationship it can't do any joins to include the associated table data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Cake must do a separate query to fetch hasMany data. In that separate query it only uses the primary key of the related model. AFAIK there's currently no way to make it use anything but the primary key. So you'll have to do these queries manually:

```
$tab1s = $this->Tab1->find('all', array(...));
$tab2s = $this->Tab2->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Tab2.tab2_md5' => Set::extract('/Tab1/tab1_md5', $tab1s))
));

$grouped = array();
foreach ($tab2s as $tab2) {
    $grouped[$tab2['Tab2']['tab2_md5']][] = $tab2;
}
foreach ($tab1s as &$tab1) {
    $tab1['Tab2'] = isset($grouped[$tab1['Tab1']['tab1_md5']]) ? $grouped[$tab1['Tab1']['tab1_md5']] : array();
}
```

Something along these lines. You could do this automatically in an `afterFind` callback in the model itself to get the Cake automagic effect.